# Karma.js with require and multiple sockets to Phantomjs

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma with Require for unit test I notice something strange. When running karma 3-4 time in row I'm getting 2-4 socket connections.

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/mja07/workspace/common-js/test/unit/**/*.mock.js" does not match any file.
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket 5xynIaiG8NOrpBDAgy34 with id 19375535
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket amsV702P869uVb23gy35 with id 17909591
```

And this is test-main.js file:

```
var tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function (file) {
  return (/(mock|spec)\.js$/).test(file);
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: 'base',
  paths: {
  angular: 'vendor/angular/angular',
  'angular-cookies': 'vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
  'angular-mocks': 'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
  'angular-route': 'vendor/angular-route/angular-route',
  'angular-sanitize': 'vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
  lodash: 'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash',
  mock: 'test/unit/mock',
  tweenlite: 'vendor/greensock/src/uncompressed/TweenLite',
  'tweenlite-css': 'vendor/greensock/src/uncompressed/plugins/CSSPlugin'
  },
  shim: {
     angular: {
     exports: 'angular'
  },
  lodash: {
     exports: '_'
  },
tweenlite: {
  deps: [
    'tweenlite-css'
     ],
     exports: 'TweenLite'
   }
  }
});

require(['config', 'angular'], function (cfg, A) {
  require(['angular-cookies', 'angular-mocks', 'angular-route', 'angular-sanitize'],     function () {
    A.module(cfg.ngApp, []);
    A.bootstrap(document, [cfg.ngApp]);

    require(tests, function () {
     window.__karma__.start();
    });
  });
});
```

Also have question how fast to debug problems with wrong path (see whole path) when I'm getting :

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /vendor/angular/angular.js
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for vendor/angular/angular.js!'
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Problem sorted. When Karma is crashing you still have previous Phantomjs process so after will you are running multiple instance of phantomjs